# Chi-square test in Python

Tags: python

I have a dataframe consisting of surveys. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWVvr.png)

In addition to Age, Gender, Social Media usage time and these related characteristics, there are a total of 50 questions with a 5-point Likert scale (1=Strongly Disagree, 5=Strongly Agree). These questions are identified with "s number" "s11,s12, ....". My aim is to find out how men and women relate to the answers given. Example = Questions s34 to s43 represent "Pre-purchase consumption behavior". In this problem, I want to find out if gender is related to pre-purchase consumption behavior, but frankly I don't understand what to do. In the dataframe, the data is not missing (in float), but in the "Crosstab" I think the data is missing, for example =s34. In summary, how can I do a chi-square test of the data I have?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7pUa.png)

I want to do a chi-square test of the relevant categorical variables. I actually tried something, but I think the result is wrong, when I did the same operations with the SPSS program before, the result was different.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3JS8.png)

Comment: Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and put the actual code as text [instead of images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)